Compatable Springdoc openapi ui version with spring 5.2.0.RELEASE
My project dependencies are here
<log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jdk.debug>true</jdk.debug>
        <jdk.optimize>false</jdk.optimize>
        <jdk.source>1.8</jdk.source>
        <jdk.target>1.8</jdk.target>

        <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.9</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-codec.version>1.11</commons-codec.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.11.2</jjwt.version>
        <jackson.version>2.10.3</jackson.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
        <guava.version>31.1-jre</guava.version>
        <caffeine.version>2.8.0</caffeine.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.10.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <validation.version>2.0.1.Final</validation.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <metrics.version>4.0.2</metrics.version>
        <cxf.version>3.2.2</cxf.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.7</httpclient.version>
        <zxing.version>3.2.1</zxing.version>

I want to add this dependency
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

Because it is a spring project, I have added this class too
    package com.hititcs.craneota.api.service.config;

import com.hititcs.crane.types.basictypes.ClientInformationType;
import com.hititcs.craneota.api.service.security.conversation.Conversation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.MediaType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponses;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocUtils;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    static {

        // RequestHeader annotation'larını ignore et.
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(RequestHeader.class);

        // Conversation ve ClientInformationType parametrelerini ignore et
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addRequestWrapperToIgnore(
            Conversation.class, ClientInformationType.class
        );

        // Tüm enum sınıflarını reusable hale çevir
        io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.enumsAsRef = true;
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components())
            .info(new Info()
                      .title("CraneOTA API Document")
                      .version(environment.getProperty("app.version", "unknown")));
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser addCustomGlobalResponseHeader() {

        Schema errorResponseSchema = new Schema();
        errorResponseSchema.setName("ErrorResponse");
        errorResponseSchema.set$ref("#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse");

        return openApi -> {
            openApi.getPaths().values().stream().flatMap(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().stream())
                .forEach(operation -> {
                    ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();
                    apiResponses.addApiResponse("400", createApiResponse("Bad Request", errorResponseSchema));
                    apiResponses.addApiResponse("403", createApiResponse("Forbidden", null));
                    apiResponses.addApiResponse("404", createApiResponse("Not Found", null));
                    apiResponses.addApiResponse("500", createApiResponse("Server Error", errorResponseSchema));

                });

        };
    }

    private ApiResponse createApiResponse(String message, Schema schema) {
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
        mediaType.schema(schema);
        return new ApiResponse().description(message)
            .content(new Content().addMediaType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, mediaType));
    }
}

and my appInitializer class is also here
    package com.hititcs.craneota.api.service.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{};
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
        registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(container);
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = getContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("swaggerDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan("rest");
        context.register(OpenApiConfiguration.class, org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
                         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
                         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
                         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.MultipleOpenApiSupportConfiguration.class,
                         org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class, org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class,
                         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class);

        return context;
    }
}

When I open the link http://localhost:8081/api/v3/api-docs, it says "No handler found for GET /api/v3/api-docs". How can I reach the swagger doc of my project from the endpoint? According to the other dependency versions, which version of Springdoc openapi should I use? Please tell me the way.
